# How to Duplicate file using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to duplicate a file using JMeter,

The scenario:

1. Loading a JSON file. For example, {"name":"John","age":"$age_place"}
2. Modify one property - age_place from 1 to 20
3. Save each modified iteration into a separate file

I have tried to do that with Simple Data Writer but it didn't work.

Comment: Add to question what you did and what failed

Answer (score 1):

You have JSR223 Elements as [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or Pre processor which you can add powerful script,

The easiest is to replace `age_place` with your value, for example if saved in variable `age_place`:

```
f = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\template.json", false);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print("{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":\"age_place\"}".replaceAll("age_place", vars.get("age_place")));
f.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate 20 files with different age you can do it using any of [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). Example [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code would look like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":\"\"}")
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json)
1.upto(20, {
    builder.content.age= "${it}"
    def writer = new File('file' + "${it}" + ".json").newWriter()
    writer << builder.toPrettyString()
    writer.close()
})
```

Once you execute your test it will create the following files in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

- `file1.json` - with the age of `1`
- `file2.json` - with the age of `2`
- ...
- `file20.json` - with the age of `20`

References:

- [Groovy For Loop Examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)